# What are the metrics for encapsulation?

Tags: java, encapsulation

What are the closest metrics (or even exact metrics) that you can use to check encapsulation?

Braking encapsulation in Object-Oriented code is one the worst thing you can do to your project (if not THE worst).

Many (if not all) of the programming principles are around different aspects encapsulation, so what metrics are most important to detect / evaluate how well/bad your code base is doing?

Comment: You may find that paper useful (quick google search with '*encapsulation metrics*'): [Analysis of object Oriented Metrics](http://www.ijceronline.com/papers/Vol2_issue5/AY02514741479.pdf)

Comment: also found (based on the previously mentioned paper defining MOOD) this master thesis : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.188&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

## A) (MOOD and MOOD2) Metrics for Object Oriented Design, by Fernando Brito and Abreu

*(details at http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-mood.html)*

Based on what they check :

- encapsulation :

  - (MHF) Method Hiding Factor
  - (AHF) Attribute Hiding Factor
- inheritance :

  - (MIF) Method Inheritance Factor
  - (AIF) Attribute Inheritance Factor
- polymorphism :

  - (POF) Polymorphism Factor
- coupling :

  - (COF) Coupling Factor

TODO : add the MOODS metrics

## B) C.K. Metrics, by Chidamber and Kemerer

*(details at http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-ck.html)*

TODO : add the MOODS metrics here